# Parent value isnt passing in Child componet:

Tags: lightning-aura-components

In javascript side im getting parent url Id.Iam trying to display in component but itsnt showing value(asb_r.url_c)

```
<aura:attribute name="Listing" type="asb_Listing__c[]"/> 
<p> value:{!v.Listing.Asb_App__r.LogoUrl__c}</p>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Child relationship name in the JSON is `asb_App__r` but in your markup, you are using `Asb_App__r`. Change relationship name to former and it will fix the issue.

> value:{!v.Listing.asb_App__r.LogoUrl__c}

Always remember everything in Lightning is case-sensitive since it uses Javascript.